# How to generate the filename as wanted?

Tags: java

I was suggested this code for solving one of my problems:

```
private static final String PATH_FMT = 
    "C:\\Users\\{0}\\Desktop\\Bloomberg Rechnung-{1,date,yyyyMMdd}{2,choice,0< ({2})}.xlsx";

private File save() throws IOException {
    Date now = new Date();
    for (int fCounter = 0; ; fCounter++) {
        Path path = Paths.get(
            MessageFormat.format(PATH_FMT, this.username, now, fCounter)
        );
        try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(path, CREATE_NEW)) {
            this.wb.write(out);
            this.wb.close();
            return path.toFile();
        } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException incrCounterAndRetry) {
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly this code does not completely do what I want. It should create a file. The first file it should create with no other file around with the name, should not have a counter. The second file that gets created should have the counter in the filename (doesn't matter where it starts). I currently get as first file a file with the counter 0. Can anyone help me to fix this problem? And maybe someone can explain to me how `{2,choice,0< ({2})}` works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `this.username` is current user, you can use this to make path more relative:  %userprofile%\\Desktop\\Bloomberg Rechnung-{1,date,yyyyMMdd}{2,choice,0< ({2})}.xlsx

Comment: I suggest you to read JavaDocs first: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Comment: already read the docs, but didn't help me solving it

Comment: What do you actually get compared to what you expect?

Comment: I currently get as first file a file with the counter 0

Comment: According to the docs, `{2,choice,0< ({2})}` should make a choice: if param 2 is 0 there is no output defined, if param 2 is > 0 it should output " (whatever value fCounter is)" Not defining anything for ==0 could be a problem though. Not sure if the default is "no output" in that case.

Comment: if the case is fCounter==0 the output is fCounter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try `{2,choice,0#|0<{2,number,integer}}`.

To explain each part

- `2` - the argument index, zero based
- `choice` - the format type, in this case a list of choices
- `0#` - in case the argument is zero, then have an empty string
- `|` - separator between choices
- `0<` - in case the argument is bigger than zero
- `{2,number,integer}` - subformat for the second choice meaning the argument with index 2 formatted as an integer.

Comment: yes this is what i wanted. would there be a way to have the counter start at 0? and could you maybe explain what exactly this does?

Comment: What do you mean by "the counter start at 0"? I added more explanations to my answer.

Comment: i mean the first file created should not have a counter in it. then second file created should have a counter in it, which starts at 0 and not at 1. its no problem if its not possible but i am just curious if its possible

Comment: You can start `fCounter` at -1 and use `{2,choice,-1#|-1<{2,number,integer}}`

Comment: ahh yeah so simple and i didn't get it myself. Thank you very much for solving my problem

Comment: Wow one hour question posting to comments to answer. Quick turn around!